# integration of VTK into QT - VS2013 : CMake Error - Qt5WebKitWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, webkit, vtk

I am trying to build VTK(6.3.0) into Qt 5.7.0. (Windows Platform - VS 2013)
.
I set the source directory and then the build directory and press Configure in CMake.

Error is

> CMake Error at C:/Qt/5.7.0/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5WebKitWidgets"
>   with any of the following names:
>
> Qt5WebKitWidgetsConfig.cmake
>
> qt5webkitwidgets-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5WebKitWidgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set "Qt5WebKitWidgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files. If "Qt5WebKitWidgets" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has been installed.
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   GUISupport/QtWebkit/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

To some extent I understood these webkit libraries were available in Qt4 version. However in Qt5.7.0 it's been deleted and incorporated into Qt webengine.

To build Qt5.7.0 I used: **configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -qt-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2013**

In another system I used Qt4.7.3: **configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -no-qt3support -qt-sql-sqlite -phonon -phonon-backend -no-webkit -no-script -platform win32-msvc2010**

However, irrespective of I skip or don't skip webkit in configure options, CMake bulid of VTK into Qt looks for QtWebkit libraries. How to make CMake to skip that option or make Webkit optional to look into?

Any leads to solve this issue is appreciated.

Regards,
Prajwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- Use a version of Qt previous to deprecation of webkit module (I think the most recent is Qt 5.3, to be verified).
- Modify the cmake files by yourself, either by disabling the parts wich depend on the webkit module (a dirty "comment all" can do the trick), or by updating the project in order to use the new webengine module.
- Send an issue to the developers of VTK and wait for them to do the job for you (**EDIT:** looks like it's already [done](http://www.vtk.org/Bug/view.php?id=15703), try VTK v7.0.0).

Comment: Yes I tried with VTK v7.0.0, the error does not reproduce. Thanks a lot. Was struggling for 3 days. Finally a solution. Thank You:)